# How to improve performance when dealing with Cursor-Movement within a Grid? (Pygame)

Tags: python, performance, grid, cursor, pygame

Ok, to move some rect with the mouse is easy as hell. Nevertheless, things are not so simple when you want to move it WITHIN a "grid".

The resolution in my game is 1024|768 by default, and the whole screen is filled with tiles of (1024/16)|(768/16). Which means 64|48. Each tile can be a wall or a player or an enemy or an item or anything.

So the cursor is a "selection cursor" that provides information about the tiles (It moves BY tiles, not by pixels).

I know how to do it, but there's a problem:

```
def move(self,pos):

    mouseX = pos[0]
    mouseY = pos[1]

    for i in range(0,16*Wall.BRICK_HEIGHT,Wall.BRICK_HEIGHT): // Brick Height = 48
        for j in range(0,16*Wall.BRICK_WIDTH,Wall.BRICK_WIDTH): // Brick Width = 64
            if (((mouseX > j) and (mouseX < (j + Wall.BRICK_WIDTH)) and (mouseY > i) and (mouseY < (i + Wall.BRICK_HEIGHT)))):
                self.x = j
                self.y = i
```

I'm running this procedure inside the main game loop:

```
while not e.Global.DONE:

game.runLanguageMenu()
game.runIntroduction()
game.runMainMenu()
game.runDungeonMenu()
game.loadStuff()
game.runPauseMenu()

event = pygame.event.poll()
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    e.Global.DONE = True
elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
    if e.Global.gameScreen == "GAME":
        game.cursor.move(event.pos) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

if e.Global.gameScreen == "GAME":
    game.player.move(pygame.key.get_pressed())
    game.runGame()

pygame.display.flip()
```

Which means that at EACH FRAME it does a bidimensional loop in order to move the mouse selection cursor through the tiles. The result? Lag, of course.
The cursor changes of tile when the mouse is inside of it. In order to check it, it's necessary to loop through all the tiles that are currently being drawn. Do you know how to do it without using a bidimensional loop in order to save some processing power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your solution by giving your blocks/tiles a *world coordinate* (that simply represents the column and row of the block inside the grid) instead of manually calculating it every time.

Then you can simply check for that after translating the mouse position to a *world coordinate*.

Futhermore, you could then create a dictionary that maps each column/row to a block/tile object (you didn't show the rest of your code, so I don't know how you actually store your tiles; maybe a list of list? If yes, then you simply retrieve the right tile with an index).

That would let you get rid of the loop.

---

Also, I think using `pygame.event.poll()` instead of `pygame.event.get()` may be an issue, too.

When using `poll` you only get one event from the event queue. That means that you can only handle one event every frame. Maybe this causes your lag?

You should check the other functions you run in your mainloop, too. I would run a profiler to see where the bottleneck of the game is (sometimes the results are suprising).

---

Here's a simple example of using a `dict` to find the tile under the mouse cursor. More explanation in the comments.

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

BRICK_HEIGHT = 48
BRICK_WIDTH = 64

class Block(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, num=0, width=0, color=(122, 122, 122)):
        # w_x and w_y represents the world coordinates
        # that means the 'column' and 'row' in the 'grid'
        self.w_x, self.w_y = x, y
        # to calculate the absolute (screen) position,
        # simply multiply x, y with BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect(x*BRICK_WIDTH, y*BRICK_HEIGHT, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT)
        self.width = width
        self.color = color

    def draw(self, surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(surface, self.color, self.rect, self.width)

    def move(self, global_pos):
        # to translate the absolute (screen) position
        # back to the world coordinates, simply divide
        # with BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT
        x, y = global_pos
        self.w_x = (x / BRICK_WIDTH)
        self.w_y = (y / BRICK_HEIGHT)
        # recalculate the absolute (screen) position,
        # so the cursor "snaps" to the grid
        self.rect.x = self.w_x * BRICK_WIDTH
        self.rect.y = self.w_y * BRICK_HEIGHT

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((10*BRICK_WIDTH, 10*BRICK_HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

c = Block(width=4, color=(200, 255, 200))

def r_color():
    return (random.randint(30, 255), 
            random.randint(30, 255),
            random.randint(30, 255))

# blocks maps (column, row) to a block
# note that this keeps the information of the
# position of a block at *two* places, which needs
# to be in sync. That's a drawback, but the
# lookup is fast!
blocks = {}
for x in xrange(10):
    for y in xrange(10):
        if random.randint(0, 100) < 33:
            blocks[(x, y)] = Block(x, y, color=r_color())

while True:
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    c.move(pos)

    for e in pygame.event.get(): 
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            raise Exception()
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # finding the tile under the mouse is as easy as:
            block = blocks.get((c.w_x, c.w_y))
            # and since it's a dict, the lookup is very fast.
            print 'Selected block color: {}'.format(block.color) if block else 'No block selected'

    screen.fill((0, 30, 30))
    for b in blocks.values():
        # The blocks calculated their absolute position by themself.
        # That may or may not what you want. Another way is to calculate
        # their absolute position here, so the blocks only needs to 
        # know about their world coordinates
        b.draw(screen)
    c.draw(screen)

    # run at 60 FPS
    clock.tick(60)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you very much. Soon after I posted the question, I discovered that the cause of the huge lag was the poll() instead of get(), indeed. Nevertheless, your solution is far more clever (Mine is probably a bit more over-complicated, considering that I "select" using a "collision approach"). No, I'm not using dicts. The world is actually procedurally generated. I generate a random dungeon of N number of mazes (Where each screen is a different maze), and they're stored in a list. Each maze is a list, and the dungeon itself is a list of Maze objects. Thank you very much!!